# AzureDevOps / Executing the pipelines locally with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to duplicate the build process (with pipelines) from Azure DevOps to my PC with Visual Studio 2019.

This could save time and git ops during the debugging/evolving phase of the pipelines.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This has been requested many times in many places, and I think that, given Microsoft's push toward Github, you may not see a lot of effort in this direction.

Right now, I don't think you'll be able to able to use VS 2019 to *directly debug* pipelines, but you can do a couple of things as a workaround:

1. Put your build process into a Powershell script and debug that process using VS Code or Powershell ISE. Then, set up your Azure Pipelines build to invoke that script. Your pipeline, and local build then are using the same mechanism to build.
2. This is more to be able to test outside any existing pipelines you may have.
   2a. Create a new agent pool for testing local pipelines.
   2b. Install the Azure Pipelines agent code, and when configuring the agent, point it to the agent pool you just created.
   2c. In a topic branch for your project, change the pool in your `azure-pipelines.yml` file to use the agent pool you just created.
   2d. Commit and push that branch.
   2e. Manually queue up a build of your project, selecting the branch you just pushed.
   2f. Debug. Wash. Rinse. Repeat
   2g. Once you've got it all sorted out, you can revert the `azure-pipelines.yml` pool change, and commit/PR the Powershell script you created.

The second option doesn't really speak directly to your question, rather it adds one more thing you can do to help with the first option - getting everything tested locally.